# I should detect selected entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()
root.config(bg='white')
root.state('zoomed')
x = np.arange(-10, 11, 1)
root.title('Fonksiyonlar')
c1 = Canvas(height=600, width=1100, bg='gray97')
import time

errortext = tk.Label(text='Girdiğiniz Sayıları Kontrol Ediniz', font='Calibri 25')

def gos():
    errortext.place_forget()

def b1c():
    def b3g():
        for i in e1.get():
            if i != '0' or '1' or '2' or '3' or '4' or '5' or '6' or '7' or '8' or '9' or '0' or '.':
                e1.delete(0, END)

                errortext.place(x=300, y=200)
                root.after(3000, gos)

    bbir.destroy()
    biki.destroy()
    c1.destroy()

    e1 = tk.Entry(highlightcolor='blue', bg='pink', font='Calibri 40')
    e1.place(width=230, height=230, x=80, y=300)
    bşş = tk.Button(text='TAMAM', command=b3g)
    bşş.pack()
    lx2 = tk.Label(text='x² + ', font='Calibri 150', bg='white')
    lx2.place(x=350, y=300)
    e2 = tk.Entry(highlightcolor='blue', bg='pink', font='Calibri 40')
    e2.place(width=230, height=230, x=700, y=300)
    lx3 = tk.Label(text='x +', font='Calibri 150', bg='white')
    lx3.place(x=1000, y=300)
    e3 = tk.Entry(highlightcolor='blue', bg='pink', font='Calibri 40')
    e3.place(width=230, height=230, x=1280, y=300)
    lx4 = tk.Label(text='=', font='Calibri 150', bg='white')
    lx4.place(x=1550, y=300)
    e4 = tk.Entry(highlightcolor='blue', bg='pink', font='Calibri 40')
    e4.place(width=230, height=230, x=1680, y=300)
    b1 = tk.Button(text='1', padx=20, pady=20, font='Calibri 20')
    b1.place(x=850, y=570)
    b2 = tk.Button(text='2', padx=20, pady=20, font='Calibri 20')
    b2.place(x=950, y=570)
    b3 = tk.Button(text='3', padx=20, pady=20, font='Calibri 20')
    b3.place(x=1050, y=570)
    b4 = tk.Button(text='4', padx=20, pady=20, font='Calibri 20')
    b4.place(x=850, y=700)
    b5 = tk.Button(text='5', padx=20, pady=20, font='Calibri 20')
    b5.place(x=950, y=700)
    b6 = tk.Button(text='6', padx=20, pady=20, font='Calibri 20')
    b6.place(x=1050, y=700)
    b7 = tk.Button(text='7', padx=20, pady=20, font='Calibri 20')
    b7.place(x=850, y=820)
    b8 = tk.Button(text='8', padx=20, pady=20, font='Calibri 20')
    b8.place(x=950, y=820)
    b9 = tk.Button(text='9', padx=20, pady=20, font='Calibri 20')
    b9.place(x=1050, y=820)
    b0 = tk.Button(text='0', padx=75, pady=20, font='Calibri 15')
    b0.place(x=850, y=930)
    beş = tk.Button(text='=', padx=22, pady=20, font='Calibri 20')
    beş.place(x=1050, y=930)
    bar = tk.Button(text='+', padx=20, pady=20, font='Calibri 20')
    bar.place(x=1150, y=570)
    bek = tk.Button(text='-', padx=22, pady=20, font='Calibri 20')
    bek.place(x=1150, y=700)
    bb = tk.Button(text='/', padx=22, pady=20, font='Calibri 20')
    bb.place(x=1150, y=930)
    bç = tk.Button(text='*', padx=20, pady=20, font='Calibri 20')
    bç.place(x=1150, y=820)

    print(e1.select_present())

c1.place(x=420, y=170)
bbir = Button(text='1.dereceden denklemler', bg='gray91', padx=300, pady=30, font='Calibri 30', command=b1c)
bbir.place(x=450, y=300)
biki = Button(text='2.dereceden denklemler', bg='gray91', padx=300, pady=30, font='Calibri 30')
biki.place(x=450, y=500)

def hesapla(a, b, c):

    return a * x ** 2 + b * x + c

m = 0.5 * x + x ** 2 + 5

plt.plot(x, hesapla(0, 0, 0))
plt.grid()

plt.show`)
```

I have tried `selectionpresent()` but it is not for it

Comment: Please try to reduce the amount of code, and the nonsense characters in your post that get around site restrictions. For example, if the question is about an entry widget, I don't think we need more 15+ buttons, or numpy or matplotlib.

Comment: Btw `i != '0' or '1' or '2' or ...` is always `True` because it's equivalent to `(i != '0') or ('1' )or ('2')` and not what you were trying to do. To fix this use `i not in '012356789'` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect the selected entry box in Tkinter, you can use the focus_get() method. It returns the widget that currently has the focus.

Comment: Eyw hocam sagolasin

Comment: @JuniorMehmet İşini halledebildin mi duruma göre daha fazla detaylı anlatmaya çalışırım. İşini hallettiysen lütfen bu cevabı doğru cevap olarak seç ki diğer kullanıcılar benzer cevaplar yazmak için vakit kaybetmesinler lütfen :) .

Comment: Hocam bir konu daha var yardımcı olabirsen sevinirim hocam ben yazı için karakter sınırlandırma koymak istiyorum örneğin her entry için 6 karakter gibi sizce nasıl yapabilirim

Comment: O farklı bir soru olduğu için şöyle yapmamız lazım sen yeni bir soru aç ve orada sor, buradan linkini paylaşırsan ben ona gidip yardımcı olmaya çalışırım. Ama senden ricam bu cevabı onaylaman çünkü görüyorum başka kullanıcılar okuyup vakit kayıp ediyorlar, bu sırada başka kişilere yardımcı olabilirler.

Comment: Tamamdır hocam haklısın hemen yeni post oluşturuyorum millet vakit kaybetmesin sağol ilgin icin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77782993/i-want-to-resize-text-automatically

Comment: Hocam onayladım olmuştur herhalde